# While running a batch file ,for some reason I couldn't see any response from my Process.Start()

Tags: c#

The batch file is not giving any response.

**The below is the code**

```
SecureString password = new SecureString(); 
foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray()) 
    password.AppendChar(c); 
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\users\Beulah_joe\Mybuilds\build";
psi.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/q /c build.cmd"; 
psi.UseShellExecute = false; 
psi.UserName = "Joe"; 
psi.Password = password; 
Process.Start(psi);
```

I am expecting some output or error message

Comment: what batch file? and what kind of error message expected?

Comment: FYI, a string can be treated as a character array directly, no need for `.ToCharArray()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After executing this batch,I do not see any error or response